# Transparent Videos not displaying correctly on the mobile version of Safari/Chrome

Tags: html, video, browser, encoding

I am currently adding transparent Videos to my online project.
I encoded the videos both in H265 for Safari as well as webm for Chrome.

```
            <video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="dance">
                <source src="vid/dance_H.265.mp4" 
                type='video/quicktime; codecs="hvc1"'>
                <source src="vid/dance_VP9.webm" 
                type="video/webm">
            </video>
```

This worked well, as the videos are perfectly displayed with a transparent background on the desktop versions of Chrome ans Safari. But when i take a look at the mobile Version in Chrome and Safari, the videos have a white background instead of being transparent. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It might be that transparent videos aren't supported, so it might be to no fault of your own